# Magento Restrict Tax for Specific Country

Tags: shipping, tax, shipping-tax

My Tax calculation is based on `Shipping Origin`. Example `UAE` is the default tax origin country, so for all the orders tax is applied. What I want is if the shipping address of customer is `UAE` or `Saudi Arabia` then tax should not be applied.

So basically i want to disable the tax for `UAE` or `Saudi Arabia` customers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solved my problem

First I imported tax rates for all the countries from the sheet and set same 5% tax (which is what I want).

Then changed `UAE` and `SAUDI ARABIA` tax to `0`(you can add it by sheet also).

And in the System -> Configuration -> tax -> tax based on shipping address.

So Now if the customer shipping address is `UAE` or `SA` no tax is applied.